# Simulator working better than real device (iphone) iOS (leaderboard + IAP purchases)

Tags: swift, error-handling, ios-simulator, leaderboard

In the simulator everything works: leaderboard, in-app purchases.

But when I test on a real iPhone, the leaderboard doesnt work(it says "Game center unavailable, playyer is not logged in") and the in-app purchases sometimes work sometimes don't..

how come?

Comment: Since GameCenter, IAP, et al work fine in other apps, you're going to need to provide a bit more information about what you're doing and what errors you are seeing.

Comment: The leaderboard: on simulator it works perfect. But on real device, it doesn't show the welcome screen when I open the app. and when I try to show leaderboard it says: Game center unavailable, player is not logged in"